# Python ctypes dtype multiply

Tags: python, python-3.x, ctypes

I have the following line in python:

```
a = (ctypes.c_float*10)()
```

Here a is initialized as an object with _*repr*_ result:

```
<__main__.c_float_Array_10 object at 0x7fbb3e6cf340>
```

My understanding is that this object is some sort of a pointer that can interoperate between python and C functions. How does this work and how are we able to multiply `ctypes.c_float` class with and integer?

Comment: What's the actual question? It's pretty much covered in [\[Python.Docs\]: ctypes - A foreign function library for Python](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#module-ctypes).

Comment: hat does it mean to multiply the c_float class with and integer. I understand the mul dunder function for object but I am not able to understand it in class context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c_float` is a *type* corresponding to C `float`.
`c_float * 10` is an array of that type corresponding to C `float[10]`.
`(c_float * 10)()` is an *instance* of the 10-element float array.

A DLL with a C function of `float sum(float* arr, size_t size);` could be called with:

```
import ctypes as ct

dll = ct.CDLL('./somelibrary.dll')

# Inform ctypes of the type of arguments and return value.
dll.sum.argtypes = ct.POINTER(ct.c_float), ct.c_size_t
dll.sum.restype = ct.c_float

# make an instance of an array of 10 float values.
a = (ct.c_float * 10)(1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.5, 6.6, 7.7, 8.8, 9.9, 10.0)
result = dll.sum(a, len(a))
```

Comment: So the pointer will be passed here between python and C with no copying?

Comment: @Tarique yes but putting the values in the array is a one time conversion from python floats to C floats, and the reverse after you get the array back and access the values, so unless you do a lot of manipulation in the C function the overhead may not be worth it.